# Entity Framework Context lifetime

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, orm

I have a WPF desktop app that using EF orm for mapping. My app have several pages
and each page has several windows. EF context is created per form. Pages in app using stateless entity only to show data the user.

My problem is that a page should update an entity for a single task and for this reason there should be a context living on this page. Therefore where I open window on this page for update other entities, there are 2 contexts active on this page.

How I can prevent this condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new class "ClientRepository" in your project. This class will contain all entity framework access logic your client has.

Use this class in all your windows and pages.

If you configure this class to behave as singleton, you will only have one entity framework context.
Ideally this can be done using a DI framework like [Microsoft Unit](https://unity.codeplex.com/) or [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/), but of course you can also do it manually.

**Singltons?**

You might ask yourself, whether its a good idea to you singletons here.

I had a similar question once and thus asked Brian Noyes (Microsoft MVP) on a "MVVM" course on the pluralsight website.

In his response he wrote: "...most of my client services are Singletons anyway and live for the life of the app."

So, for a client service, its ok to have a singleton.